# Limiting Input Parameter to only File Geodatbase in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, python-toolbox

I've been working with ESRI Python toolboxes for a while but I'm still having difficulties setting an input parameter as a "DEWorkspace" and using the parameter filter to make it so only file geodatabases are visible to the end user when entering parameters.

I'm using 10.5 and this is the [ESRI documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)

```
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Input Workspace",
    name="in_workspace",
    datatype="DEWorkspace",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

# Set the filter to accept only local (personal or file) geodatabases
    param0.filter.list = ["Local Database"]
    params = [param0]
    return params
```

The problem I'm encountering is that this filter doesn't seem to actually limit what the end user can see or enter as parameter. For example when they navigate to provide a file geodatabse the dialog allows them to see and enter .lyr files. 
[image]

I'm assuming that you should be able to limit what the end user can see and enter when it comes to workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it only occurs with the combination of *.lyr files and "Local Database" filter, but other types of files are filtered out as expected. The filter works fine for the other workspace type options.

As a workaround, you can check by yourself that the input value is indeed a file geodatabase and then use the internal validation of the tool to add a warning or error message:

```py
def updateMessages(self, parameters):

    workspace = parameters[0].valueAsText

    if not os.path.isdir(workspace) or not os.path.splitext(workspace)[-1] == ".gdb":
        parameters[0].setWarningMessage("This is not a File Geodatabase")

    return
```